# Connecting to my smart contract on polygon testnet (Mumbai)

Tags: web3js, polygon

I created a smart contract (lets call it `MyContract`) and deployed it on Mumbai testnet.
I used [this tutorial](https://wiki.polygon.technology/docs/develop/ethereum-polygon/matic-js/get-started) to connect to `MyContract`. this is my code:

```
import maticjs from '@maticnetwork/maticjs';
const { POSClient,use } = maticjs;
import maticjsWeb3 from '@maticnetwork/maticjs-web3';
const { Web3ClientPlugin } = maticjsWeb3;
import HDWalletProvider from "@truffle/hdwallet-provider";
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()

// install web3 plugin
use(Web3ClientPlugin);

const posClient = new POSClient();

let fromAddress = "<my private address (also the miner of the contract)>";

await posClient.init({
    network: 'testnet',
    version: 'mumbai',
    parent: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, process.env.MUMBAI_RPC_URL)
    },
    child: {
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, process.env.MUMBAI_RPC_URL),
      defaultConfig: {
        from : fromAddress
      }
    }
});

const erc20ChildToken = posClient.erc20("<MyContract address>");

const balance = await erc20ChildToken.getBalance(fromAddress);
console.log('balance', balance/10**18);


const result = await erc20ChildToken.stake(10);
console.log('result ', result)
```

as you can see in the last 2 rows I have a call `erc20ChildToken.stake` by which I intended to call the `stake` function of the contract, but I get this error:

`TypeError: erc20ChildToken.stake is not a function`

How can I access "special" functions that are not part of the standard ERC20 interface?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the correct ABI and create a contract with it. You can also use a low-level call but the better way is with the correct ABI.

Comment: how do I do that? can you share a code example? or maybe a guide online? haven't found anything good when I searched

Comment: Do you want it specific to maticJS or you don’t mind?

Comment: I don't mind, as long as it works for polygon